# Difficulty numerically integrating highly oscilliatory function

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the following two integrals that I wish to numerically integrate. The function in each integral is the same. They have been split up since at t = 0 there's a singularity.

```
p=0.03

    Rzz1[x_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := 1/(\[Pi] p)
   NIntegrate[ (-Log[((2 x - 1 + Sqrt[
           4 x^2 - 4 x + 1 + 4 t^2]) (- 2 x - 1 + Sqrt[
           4 x^2 + 4 x + 1 + 4 t^2]))/(4 t^2)] - 
      Log[(-2 x + 1 + Sqrt[4 x^2 - 4 x + 1 + 4 t^2 + 4 p^2])/(- 2 x - 
        1 + Sqrt[4 x^2 + 4 x + 1 + 4 t^2 + 4 p^2])]) Cos[k t], {t, 0, 
    1}]



Rzz2[x_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := 
 1/(\[Pi] p)
   NIntegrate[ (-Log[((2 x - 1 + Sqrt[
           4 x^2 - 4 x + 1 + 4 t^2]) (- 2 x - 1 + Sqrt[
           4 x^2 + 4 x + 1 + 4 t^2]))/(4 t^2)] - 
      Log[(-2 x + 1 + Sqrt[4 x^2 - 4 x + 1 + 4 t^2 + 4 p^2])/(- 2 x - 
        1 + Sqrt[4 x^2 + 4 x + 1 + 4 t^2 + 4 p^2])]) Cos[k t], {t, 
    1, \[Infinity]}]


Rzz[x_, k_] := Rzz1[x, k] + Rzz2[x, k]
```

The values that x takes are given below:

```
{-0.495, -0.485, -0.475, -0.465, -0.455, -0.445, -0.435, -0.425, \
-0.415, -0.405, -0.395, -0.385, -0.375, -0.365, -0.355, -0.345, \
-0.335, -0.325, -0.315, -0.305, -0.295, -0.285, -0.275, -0.265, \
-0.255, -0.245, -0.235, -0.225, -0.215, -0.205, -0.195, -0.185, \
-0.175, -0.165, -0.155, -0.145, -0.135, -0.125, -0.115, -0.105, \
-0.095, -0.085, -0.075, -0.065, -0.055, -0.045, -0.035, -0.025, \
-0.015, -0.005, 0.005, 0.015, 0.025, 0.035, 0.045, 0.055, 0.065, \
0.075, 0.085, 0.095, 0.105, 0.115, 0.125, 0.135, 0.145, 0.155, 0.165, \
0.175, 0.185, 0.195, 0.205, 0.215, 0.225, 0.235, 0.245, 0.255, 0.265, \
0.275, 0.285, 0.295, 0.305, 0.315, 0.325, 0.335, 0.345, 0.355, 0.365, \
0.375, 0.385, 0.395, 0.405, 0.415, 0.425, 0.435, 0.445, 0.455, 0.465, \
0.475, 0.485, 0.495}
```

I am primarily interested in computing these integrals for various values of k which is the wavenumber. For instance I have been trying to compute it for 4.0*10^8 but I haven't had much luck. I've tried using various different methods but I still get a number of errors. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `k` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann k is the wavenumber so its varies but for the moment I'm looking at k = 4.0 x 10^8.

Comment: Change p to 3/100, change x to -495/1000 or 495/1000, change k to 4*10^8, (in other words all constants have no decimal points and infinite precision, but having more than 64 digits of precision might work as well, didn't test that) add WorkingPrecision->64 and MaxRecursion->1000 to your integrals and it integrates without any warnings at all.

Comment: For the two x values and one k value I tried MaxRecursion->25 still gives warnings while it may be the case that MaxRecursion->50 and above give no warnings.